# Show svg foreign element with D3.js on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I have an svg group and when I hover the mouse above it I want to show additional elements of the group. I have the code at a point where it does work in reverse (e.g. when I hover the mouse above the `g` the additional elements are hidden):
[It works in reverse (JSfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/8ptjczof/)

But when I change it so that the button is initially hidden and then gets visible on hover it does not work anymore: [How I actually want it.](https://jsfiddle.net/scjj2n61/)

I am sorry I couldn't use the built in stackoverflow code viewer, it somehow refused to work.

I think the problem is that the body tag surrounding the button stays at `opacity: 0` even after the hove event is triggered. It is easy to observe in the browsers *Inspector*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `opacity` in the `<button>` element itself:

```
.html(`<button style="color: #000000; background-color: #FF8C00; 
    border: 1px solid #888888; opacity:0" class="connector-button">
    <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`);
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7eoamnn4/